# Elevated Rights Error when trying to deploy SSIS packages to a remote server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

this is a new staging server with SQL 2008.  I'm not famliary with SSIS that much so trying to deploy a couple packages.  So I do the following in BIDS..which is probably typical:

1. Right-click my solution, go to properties, then go to the deployment utility tab
2. Change CreateDeploymentUtility to true
3. Go and find the .SSISDeploymentManifest file locally on my machine
4. Run it and try to perform a SQL Server deployment to the customer's remote server (we're running vpn to get to it)
5. I put in the fully qualified remote server's name, my windows auth or SQL account (I tried both ways)
6. Try to click now the Package Path and get this:

   ### TITLE: Package Installation Wizard

   An OLE DB error 0x80040E09 (The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_listpackages', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.) occurred while enumerating packages. A SQL statement was issued and failed.

   ---

   ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

   An OLE DB error 0x80040E09 (The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_ssis_listpackages', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.) occurred while enumerating packages. A SQL statement was issued and failed.

   ---

   BUTTONS:

   ### OK

So what do I do?  How do I essentially run this as an administrator to get past this stupid elevated rights security error?

Comment: What permission do you have on SQL server 2008 for running the package ?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your windows / sql account to `sysadmin` role.

In SQL Server Management Studio, go to Security -> Server Roles and double click `sysadmin`. Add your login and it should work when you try again.